# How to Identify the Type of a Principal?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, aws-iot

I have a situation where a Thing can have multiple principals attached to it, but each Principal is One to One with the Thing.

Ie: Thing A, gets a unique Certificate and a unique Role with unique policies. No two Things can have the same exact certificate/roles. No two Certificates/Roles can have the same policies.

In order to figure this out, I run ListPrincipalThings and am met with an array of Strings that represent each principal. The problem however is, it seems like each Principal has their own steps that I need to take before I can delete the Principal.

For the instance of deleting a Certificate, I have to:

- detach the policy
- delete the policy
- detach the certificate from the Thing
- update certificate to Inactive
- then delete the certificate.

My question is, is there some kind of built-into-the-SDK way to just pass the Principals to the AWS API and be returned with the TYPE of the principal. That way I can just pass off the principal to a different sequence for tear down in my code.

The last thing that I want to do is write a Regex function that figures out the type of the Principal and then determines based off the result what tear-down sequence it needs to follow. Not because it's difficult/complicated, but because I feel like it's prone to edge cases.

This one hundred percent could just be an X Y problem that I am missing, but thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you share the principals list you get back? There is no such a API call to return the principal type. That's why I was asking for the return, maybe as you mentioned there are regex pattern that can be applied in order to filter them out.

Comment: For reference I'm working in Rust, and I think this might be something I'm looking for https://docs.rs/aws-arn/latest/aws_arn/index.html
At the very least, this will break apart the ARN in a neat little way.